# How to sync my contacts with their gmail account?

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, nexus-4, facebook

I have bought Nexus 4 and i have imported phone contacts from my older Phone. I don't have email id for many of the contacts,i have just their phone numbers alone. Now i want to sync them with their email. Is there any way to do this. And is there any way to sync them with their fb account. (To be clear my question is if i can sync them to their gmail or fb by just using their Number). Actually i have 'Add Connection' option in 'People' tab and i'm able to get the contacts from Google Plus correctly. But when i add them to circles they are saved as separate contact and my old contact with phone number alone as separate contact.

Comment: You might wish to check [other questions tagged contacts+sync](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts+sync), which might provide useful details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could first add a facebook account from

```
 Settings->Account->Add new account->Facebook
```

Then the FB contacts will get synced with their numbers if users have added it on facebook. After that try syncing with the Google account.

If this does not work, you could always use the 'link contacts' option provided in almost all contact application. it will detect similar accounts and link them to form a single contact file.

Hope this helps!

[Import Facebook contects to Goole+](http://www.wikihow.com/Import-Your-Facebook-Friends-to-Google%2B).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i have no option to Add Facebook account in settings tab from Nexus 4. I don't know if its an issue between Facebook and Google.

Comment: You will need to first install the facebook app

Comment: yes i downloaded uber facebook sync and able to sync only 20 existing contacts. I want to sync other 200 existing contacts manually as i can do with 'Add connections' in 'People' app. Is there any way for that?

Comment: Online Contatcs Sync using [FullContact](http://www.fullcontact.com/) or [FullContact - Google Sync](http://www.fullcontact.com/features/sync-google-contacts/).

Comment: Using [Google Contact Sync](http://heartofangel.com/google-contact-sync/).

Using Google Play App [Sync.ME](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syncme.syncmeapp).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create or import your contacts under Google account. You can add both Email or Facebook info under each contacts. You can also log in to Facebook app and sync Facebook contacts. Same name will be linked automatically and you may need link manually for the remaining contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Only those contacts will sync with Gmail that are fed or created as Google accounts. Some phones do not give this choice while the contact is being created and so, it is just a phone contact.

To sync these contacts with Gmail, you have to edit such contacts. Use the following steps:

- Go to contacts.
- Click edit contact.
- On top of the contact above the name will appear Phone Contact".
- Tap it to open other option. You will see:

  - Google
  - SIM
  - Phone
- Choose Google.

Now your contact has been saved under Google. When you sync your account it will be synced to your Gmail account.

Let me know if you face problems after this!

Cheers!